# Custom parser, how to make conditional statment?

Tags: php, parsing

I have my own template engine. It can converts variable like this:

```
html html html (=array.value) html html
```

with something like this (using regex):

```
html html html $array['value'] html html
```

Now I would be able to use conditional statament. Something like:

```
html html html
(if (condition))
 (=array.value)
(endif)
html html html
```

How can I make such parser without having to use `eval`?

Comment: Parentheses are far too common in HTML/Javascript to use as your tags!

Comment: I recommend you look at the [template engines out there](https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=PHP&q=template&repo=&langOverride=&x=0&y=0&start_value=1) to see how they do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess to do such kind of evaluations you need to actually implement a full parser/lexer. I.e. split everything into tokens, build an AST and parse it. of course that depends on how complex your conditions can be.

But if you want to do stuff like `(=array.value)` you probalby need to code your own mini-scripting language.

While not exactly PHP/HTML related, i found [this](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/) pretty helpful to get a grasp on what compilers/parsers/lexers are actually doing.

Or of couse, as you mentioned, just use php and eval it, that's the easiest way.